# "ValueError : list.remove(x): x not in list" when x is in list

Tags: python

I have tried many possible solutions but none of them worked. My code is a simple word counter that counts the frequency of words in song lyrics. Since short words should't be counted I wrote this code. My word and their count lists look like this.

```
 goodwords=["a", "my", "the", "I", "long", "up", "on"] 
 count=[26, 16, 16, 15, 12, 11, 11 ]
```

So I wrote this code to filter out short words.

```
for word in goodwords:
if len(word)<3:
        goodwords.index(word)
        count.remove(goodwords.index(word))
        goodwords.remove(word)
```

Python throws me this error:

> ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Even when I try to assign the index of the word to an int the same error is shown.

Comment: Why haven't you used a dictionary for this?

Comment: You try to use `remove` once to remove a word, and once to remove an index - it can't do both.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille they're removing from two different lists.

Comment: `goodwords.index` is guaranteed to return a number less than the length of `goodwords`, which is 7; so the list `count` which contains only numbers greater than 10 cannot contain the value you are trying to remove. Why do you believe your code is correct?

Comment: @bereal What I meant was probably unclear: the OP tries once to remove a word by passing it to `remove`, and once to remove a count by passing **its index** to `remove`, but the same method can't work one way in a case and another way in another case. He meant to use `del` in the second case.

Comment: As you can see from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), `remove` expects an **element** from the list to be removed. When you do `count.remove(goodwords.index(word))` you try to remove the actual index (as a number) from the list `count`. Imagine for the first word `"a"`, its index is `0` - but there is no `0` in `count`... You might have meant to do `del count[goodwords.index(word)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not modify a list while you are iterating through it. Your indices are changing when you remove something. Tr to simplify the task.

I would store word counts in a dictionary:

```
goodwords = ["a", "my", "the", "I", "long", "up", "on"]
count = [26, 16, 16, 15, 12, 11, 11 ]
wordcounts = dict(zip(goodwords, count))
```

To have only longer words, filter them:

```
wordcounts = {word: c for word, c in wordcounts.items()
              if len(word) > 3}
```

BTW, you can get the first part of the job done using the built-in [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> wordcounts = collections.Counter("one word and one more word".split())
>>> wordcounts
Counter({'one': 2, 'word': 2, 'and': 1, 'more': 1})
```

Comment: This would be a great solution, thanks. But python gives me an "invalid syntax" error for the second(filtering) part of your code. I'm not that good with comprehensions. Could you explain?

Comment: @TavaSencaSencis I had an error in `wordcounts = dict(zip(goodwords, count)`. I forgot to close the last parenthesis. This could have shown up as an error in the line after it. Try now.

Answer (score 0):

You can affect the loop if you modify a list you're looping in.
Try creating a new list with the correct values instead.

```
for word in allwords:
if len(word)>3:
        goodwords.append(word)
```